# Should functions always return something (Javascript)

Tags: function

Should functions always return something? I often write very basic functions which are used as shorthand to do things that happen a lot such as:

```
function formsAway() {
    $("#login_form, #booking_form").slideUp();
}
```

Should this function exist - is there a better way, or is this fine?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They don't have to return anything. If you leave it blank it simply returns 'undefined' which in this case is fine because you never intend to use the return value. The Javascript syntax is pretty simplistic and as far as I know there just isn't any real distinction between functions that do and functions that don't return a value (other than the 'return' keyword)

Answer (score 6):

All JavaScript functions return something.  If an explicit return is omitted, *undefined* is returned automatically instead. When a function returns, its instance is wiped out from memory, which also frees all the variables in its scope to be wiped out if nothing else points to them. Without a forced return memory management would have to be done manually.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, unless you need it to return something, a function doesn't have to return anything.

It may be different in other languages, but I've never heard it being necessary or good practice in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

> Should functions always return
>   something?

I believe that totally depends on the usage of the function.

> is there a better way, or is this
>   fine?

IMO writing these kind of functions is good when there are many occurrences of the reusable code which can be replaced by the function so that the code looks much cleaner. But only for a couple of occurrences you may just put the code as it is instead of replacing it with function. You should also take into account the chances of reuse of this function in other places in future.