# What do I need a return statement for in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around the return statement but I can't see a reason why I should use one. My code works just fine without using one...
In both examples my console prints out `10` not matter if I use return or not.

Without return:

```
var sum = 5;

function myFunction() {
    sum += 5;
}

myFunction();

console.log(sum);
```

With return:

```
var sum = 5;

function myFunction() {
    return sum += 5;
}

myFunction();

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Your `sum` variable is declared in a scope such that it is visible both inside the function and outside where the function is called. That is not always the situation, however.

Comment: In this case, you are using the function in the same context that the variable are declared. Is the same case when you use a global variable. So indeed, there is no problem if no using returning. You may have problem when this function is used in another context, e.g., called by another script.

Comment: What about if you have 100 other functions all in different files? Real functions should take input and return output. Here your functions are more 'procedures' modifying global state. You use functions to encapsulate individual pieces of logic.

Comment: They don't have to always return something. If you leave it blank, it will return 'undefined'. Here is another question related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415247/should-functions-always-return-something-javascript

Comment: Well, in this limited example, you don't do anything with the returned value and instead rely on a global value.  So in this case `return` does nothing that you need.  That doesn't necessarily mean that the `return` keyword itself isn't useful in the language.  It's both possible and common for programmers to write larger and more complex programs than what you have here.

Comment: In a nutshell: that's not a very typical use of functions, and if you'd start writing actually useful functions, the question would somewhat answer itself.

Comment: OK, without a `return` how would you use `parseInt`, for example? Which would be the global variable that would hold the result of this function? What about `parseFloat()` or `isNaN()`, etc?  Would each have its own result variable that you have to *remember*? Would there be a single result variable? What about the array methods - `arr.map().filter().reduce()` would be impossible to do without return values.

Comment: `but I can't see a reason why I should use one`  You will see a reason when it comes time to need a reason.  Coding is pretty much like that,.. I remember lots of people not seeing any reason for Promises, until the day they started using them.. :)

Comment: This is when you want to do a return: `console.log(myFunction(sum));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, functions return the value *undefined*. If you want the function to return some other value, you need to have a return statement.

You may also use a return statement to halt execution of the function based on some logic, again returning a value that has some meaning or just undefined.

In the first example in the OP, the function is called and the return value is not used for anything, so it doesn't matter what the return value is and a return statement isn't necessary.

In another scenario, the return value might be important, e.g. a function that generates an integer random number between 0 and 10:

```js
function getRandomInteger(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
}

function showRandomNumber() {
  document.getElementById('s0').textContent = getRandomInteger();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showRandomNumber()">Show random number</button>
<span id="s0"></span>
```

In the above, the *getRandomInteger* function needs to return a specific value, so it uses a return statement. The *showRandomNumber* function just displays the random number, so it doesn't need a return statement as the caller (the listener on the button) doesn't care what the return value is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening with your example:

```
var sum = 5; //Sets the sum to =5

function myFunction() {
    return sum += 5; // += reassigns the global (sum) to 10
}

myFunction();

console.log(sum);
```

A better example would be this:

```
 sum = 5;
 function myFunction() {
     var sumOther = sum + 5;
     return sumOther;
} 
console.log(“sum:” + sum); // 5
console.log(“myFunction:” + myFunction()); // 10
```

This is how you would get the run of the function and not the global variable ‘sum’

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use (global) variable declared outside the function (function modify it directly so there is no need to return value). **However it is not good way of write functions because they are less reusable because they need proper global context to be used**. Better is to use something like this:

```js
function myFunction(num) {
  return num += 5;
}

var sum = 5;
var result = myFunction(5) ;
console.log(result); // -> 10
```

this function can be easily used ind different context because it have parameter `num` and works only on it (function uses only values declared inside its declaration and body)

Answer (score 0):

The trick in your case a is scope of a function. In both cases variable sum is defined in global scope. When you calling the function, it goes through the following steps:

1. Look whether var sum is defined in current step Since it not defined
   inside the function, go one step over and take a look into outer
   scope. Yes, it is defined here, start using it.
2. Perform calculation.
   You are using incremental operator `sum += 5` so actually it can be
   written as `sum = sum + 5`. If you will look into second case,
   you'll notice that variable have increased value now. And since that
   variable is taken from global scope, your function just mutates it.
   **NOTE: At this point no matter whether you are returning something
   from function or not. Your function just mutated outer variable.**
3. The last step - exit from function. As I said earlier, return value
   matters only if you want to use result of function call directly,
   for instance: `var result = myFunction()`